# Is there anyway to restrict registration on a ninja form (wordpress) to allow only a certain email address to register?

Tags: forms, wordpress, email-validation

this is a wordpress related question.  I was wondering while using the ninja forms plugin, if it is possible to restrict the submission process to only allow @example.com email address to successfully submit the form.

Any ideas? I appreciate the time and responses from you all.

Answer (score 0):

Please post the code for your form (even the generated html) so that the question stands the test of time!

You can do something like this in jQuery:

```
$('#signup').submit(function() {
    validateEmail($('input').val());
    return false;
});

function validateEmail(email) {
    var re = /^\s*[\w\-\+_]+(\.[\w\-\+_]+)*\@[\w\-\+_]+\.[\w\-\+_]+(\.[\w\-\+_]+)*\s*$/;
    if (re.test(email)) {
        if (email.indexOf('@c-e.com', email.length - '@c-e.com'.length) !== -1) {
            alert('Submission was successful.');
        } else {
            alert('Email must be a CE e-mail address (your.name@c-e.com).');
        }
    } else {
        alert('Not a valid e-mail address.');
    }
}
```

I found it in this working fiddle by Erik Woods:

http://jsfiddle.net/AkuXC/86/